# Sort a Map values apex

Tags: apex, map, sort

I have a map of

```
Map<String,Decimal> test = new Map<String,Decimal>();
```

In this map i am adding values like classname and codepercentagecovered and iterating over the map and creating dynamic table and adding them.

```
      test.put('testclass',0);
         test.put('zclass2',30);
        test.put('aclass1',0);


    If(test!=null && !test.isEmpty()){
                for(String s : test.keySet()){
                    strText += '<tr><td>' + s + '</td>';
                    strText += '<td>' + test.get(s) + '%'+'</td>'; 
                }  
            }
```

The table looks like this

```
testclass            0
zclass1              30
aclass1              0
```

How i can sort the map values so that it starts from 0 and then 30 at last.

Comment: You should probably try sorting before putting in map

Answer (score 4):

There is a work around that I always use for such case.

1. Take `keySet()` of the map.
2. Convert the set from Step 1. to List and sort it.
3. Iterate through sorted list and for each `element` display `map.get(element)`

Answer (score 0):

I have achieved the resolution using comparable interface

```
public class Testwrapper implements Comparable {
    public String s;
    public decimal d;
    public Testwrapper (String s, Decimal d) {
        this.s= s;
        this.d= d;
    }
    public Integer compareTo(Object other) {
        return Integer.valueof(d-((Testwrapper )other).d);
    }
}
```