# Apex Keyset- Sort values in DESC order while binding to picklist

Tags: apex, visualforce, soql, picklist, sort

I am trying to sort values in desc order before binding these to picklist. 
I have referred to some posts regarding sorting([This post](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/220023/sort-a-map-values-apex)) and implemented the below:

1. Take keySet() of the map.
2. Convert the set from Step 1. to List and sort it.
3. Iterate through sorted list and for each element display 
   map.get(element)

---

```
       // Get data from custom object using SOQL Query

        List<MyObj__c> ObjData = [Select Id, Rel__C from MyObj__c where Name__c=:searchByName];
        if(ObjData<>null && ObjData.size()>0)
        {
                 for(MyObj__c relObj:ObjData)
                 {
                        mapOfRel.put(relObj.Id,relObj.Rel__C);

                 }
        }
        //Below is the list to bind values to picklist.
        List<SelectOption> lstValues = new List<SelectOption>();
        if(mapOfRel<>null && mapOfRel.keySet()<>null){
                    lstValues.sort();
                    lstValues.add(new SelectOption('-None-','-None-')); 

                    for(String getIdValue:mapOfRel.keySet()){
                        lstValues.add(new SelectOption(getIdValue,mapOfRel.get(getIdValue)));    
                    }
                   // lstValues.sort();
            }
        system.debug('%%%%%%'+lstValues);
        return lstValues;
```

lstValues is still not sorted. 
Can anyone suggest where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 2):

The post you linked isn't applicable to your situation.

Just sort the original query, and you're done.

```
SelectOption[] options = new SelectOption[] { new SelectOption('','-- none --') };
for(Obj__c record: [SELECT ... FROM Obj__c WHERE ... ORDER BY ... DESC]) {
  options.add(new SelectOption(record.Id, record.SomeLabel));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

sort method used within the for loop.it is properly worked.
// Get data from a custom object using SOQL Query

```
    List<MyObj__c> ObjData = [Select Id, Rel__C from MyObj__c where Name__c=:searchByName];
    if(ObjData<>null && ObjData.size()>0)
    {
             for(MyObj__c relObj:ObjData)
             {
                    mapOfRel.put(relObj.Id,relObj.Rel__C);

             }
    }
    //Below is the list to bind values to picklist.
    List<SelectOption> lstValues = new List<SelectOption>();
    if(mapOfRel<>null && mapOfRel.keySet()<>null){
                lstValues.sort();
                lstValues.add(new SelectOption('-None-','-None-')); 

                for(String getIdValue:mapOfRel.keySet()){
           lstValues.sort();
                    lstValues.add(new SelectOption(getIdValue,mapOfRel.get(getIdValue)));    
                }

        }
    system.debug('%%%%%%'+lstValues);
    return lstValues;
```

Please mark it as Best if it helps you.

Thanks
Ajay

Comment: The values which I am trying to sort contain decimals in this format and are not text format but the field in the object is of text type : 1,2,3.2,3.1,14.2